# What's wrong with my tree structure?

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to figure out why tree is not printing.

```
 (define make-tree cons)
 (define root car)
 (define branches cdr) 

 (define t (make-tree 2 (make-tree 3 4)))

 (define (print tree)
     (if (null? (branches tree)) '())
        (sentence (root tree) 
                  (map (lambda(branch)(print branch))) (branches tree)))))

 (define (print2 tree)
     (if (null? (branches tree)) '())
        (sentence (root tree) (print2 (branches tree)))

 (print t)
```

I get wrong type of argument in stk-scheme.

Comment: `(map (lambda(branch)(print branch)))` in your code is probably wrong. And you don't show the definition of `sentence`.

Comment: In addition to that `map`, `(if (null? (branches tree)) '())` is also wrong. You need to pay more attention to your parentheses, and an editor that's capable of indenting Lisp-like languages helps.